# Why React router v4 makes incorrect redirect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a simple `React` app and I'm trying to implement auth logic. This is how my application looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div className="App">
                    <Switch>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/account" component={Account} />
                        <Route component={PublicLayout} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

My auth logic is: if user `isAuthenticated === true` render `/account` page else redirect to `/signin`. So for this I created my own simple `PrivateRoute` functional component:

```
export default ({ component: Component, ...args }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route {...args} render={(props) => {
                return fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : <Redirect to='/signin' />
            }} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Because `PrivateRoute path="/account"` is NOT `exact` path I expect that if user goes to `/account-setting` it will redirect him to `/sign-in`. But it's not working. The user successfully goes to `/account-setting` and see PublicLayout.

Why is that? There is no `exact` key in route, it has to grab all that starts from "/account" and use my logic in the PrivateRoute functional component.

Comment: Why do you need to redirect? Just render the `/signin` component. Besides that, now you are using a fakeAuth but you might consider using a main `Auth` and redirect from there since the auth process might be async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not providing `exact` props doesn't mean that it will match `/account`, `/account-settings` but it will match `/account`, `/account/other`, `/account/other/paths`. So, you'll need to provide both path:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/account" component={Account} />
<PrivateRoute path="/account-setting" component={Account} />
```

Or, you may use regex:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/account(?=\S*)([a-zA-Z-]+)" component={Account} />
```

Comment: Glad to help you.